# Error with blkarray: Misplaced \noalign

Tags: arrays

I am trying to write a matrix with indices given to the rows and columns. I get the error "Misplaced \noalign." Does anybody understand why? The minimal example is below.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{blockarray}{ccccc}
      & A & B & C & D\\
    \begin{block}{c[cccc]}
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 
    B & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
    C & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
    D & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0
    \end{block}
  \end{blockarray}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: You're missing the final ``\\`` in the block.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's an end of line `\\` missing at the end of the block:

Further, the example doesn't run with the `minimal` class, since the command `\footnotesize` is required by `blkarray`, it requires that command for table notes support.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{blockarray}{ccccc}
      & A & B & C & D\\
    \begin{block}{c[cccc]}
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 
    B & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
    C & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
    D & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
    \end{block}
  \end{blockarray}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: block array example]

Comment: Thanks for this quick answer! Testing buggy code with the minimal class is not a very good idea...

Comment: @Bruno: What then is the *point* of the `minimal` class?  It cuts out so much that it breaks packages that expect a normal document.

Comment: @RyanReich: Actually, I don't know... I was using it because the problem occurred to me in a beamer document and the errors are usually a bit tricky to localize in a beamer source. But I should have used the article class instead!

Comment: @Bruno: Just to be clear, I wasn't criticizing you so much as wondering why this class exists.  `article` is fairly minimal as it is.  Certainly compared to `beamer`!