# How can i put letter on the top of each column of matrix?

Tags: matrices

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\[

\implies
\mathbf{B}^c=
\begin{bmatrix}

\begin{array}{@{}ccc|ccc|c@{}}


\mathbf{-I} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{I} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} \\
\mathbf{0} & \mathbf{-I} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{I} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0}\\
 \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{-I} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{I} & \mathbf{0}\\
 \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{-I} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{I}\\
 \end{array}
 \end{bmatrix}

 \]

\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could put your MWE into once block that can be easily copy&pasted.

Comment: no, that link does not help

Comment: @user224189 -- Can you say specifically why that link doesn't help/

Answer (score 2):

With `{pNiceArray}` of `nicematrix`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,booktabs}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[
\mathbf{B}^c=
\begin{bNiceArray}{ccc|ccc|c}[first-row]
\mathbf{u}_c^{\mathbf{N}} & \mathbf{u}_e^{\mathbf{N}} & \mathbf{u}_o^{\mathbf{N}} 
& \mathbf{u}_c^{\mathbf{R}}&\mathbf{u}_e^{\mathbf{R}} & \mathbf{u}_o^{\mathbf{R}}
& \mathbf{u}_c^{\mathbf{OV}} \\
\mathbf{-I} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{I} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} \\
\mathbf{0} & \mathbf{-I} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{I} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0}\\
 \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{-I} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{I} & \mathbf{0}\\
 \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{-I} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{I}\\
 \end{bNiceArray}
 \]

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 1):

Package `blkarray` can be your friend. An anexmple  of it use (stolen from [blkarray](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34355/error-with-blkarray-misplaced-noalign)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{blockarray}{ccccc}
      & A & B & C & D\\
    \begin{block}{c[cccc]}
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 
    B & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
    C & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
    D & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
    \end{block}
  \end{blockarray}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

You only need to replace cells' contents with your data and add missed columns in matrix.